# logic iterate sort option

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts, struts-1

Is there any propety or option is there to sort the logic iterate values?

For example, I have a logic iterate like this:

```
<logic:iterate name="testForm" property="rows" id="row" type="com.mam.dto.TestDTO">
  <td class="formListLabelStyle"><bean:write name="row" property="customerLastName"/></td>
  <td class="formListLabelStyle"><bean:write name="row" property="category"/></td>  
</logic:iterate>
```

For this output will come in descending order. Here I need to sort this in asecending order. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 3):

`logic:iterate` is a tag from Struts. Struts is an MVC framework. The JSP should just generate markup. Sorting a collection is the responsibility of the action which forwards to the JSP.

Also, note that logic tags and bean:write are deprecated in favor of the JSTL for years. You should definitely help yourself, and learn the JSTL.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the collection returned by getRows() using Collections.sort() before returning the response or display using a sortable table.

Comment: Or even better, use a sorted collection like `TreeSet`.